# Why does the user accounts tab not show all my accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts

Why are not all of my accounts shown when I go to the accounts tab under my SE user profile?

The main one that I would like to be there is *English Language & Usage*.
I've used the same Google openId for all my accounts.

I found this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71254/159644
but it has no confirmed answer or activity for a long time?

Here is a detailed example of my issue:

1. I'm on EL&U
2. I go to my EL&U profile page
3. I click network profile (which brings me to my SE profile page)
4. From my SE profile I click accounts
5. There I see some of my accounts (but not all; EL&U being one that is not listed)

Why would EL&U not be there. After all, I got to that page from EL&U.

Perhaps it is like that by design and I'm just missing something. I would think my SE account would act as an umbrella to the others (not for reputation, just as a holder).   Do others have this issue?

**Update**

<strike>I tried clicking *Copy EL&U Profile To Related Accounts* from my EL&U profile page (as linked by @Grace in the comments below). Just thought I'd give it a shot. It changed nothing.</strike>

See my answer for the solution.

Comment: I can see it just fine [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/65140ef9-8dba-4590-8333-f7eacfa5e637?tab=accounts) - don't you? Maybe you reached different page?

Comment: @Shadow I'm not seeing English Language & Usage there, like logicbird purports. I'm not seeing that on any of logicbird's associated accounts, actually. Could you post a screenshot with EL&U shown there? For others, [here is the EL&U account that is not being listed](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/7200/logicbird?tab=accounts).

Comment: @ShadowWizard, no I don't see it even when I use your link. I tried to add a screenshot showing that it is not there, however, I don't have the rep to do that yet. thanks @GraceNote for confirming that it is not there.

Comment: @Grace thought that he means Unix and Linux, wasn't even aware of `English Language & Usage`. Disregard my previous comment..

Comment: "wasn't even aware of English Language & Usage" - probably because it never shows up. lol, just kidding. I just always see users abbreviating the name of any particular stack so I thought it would be alright. I edited my question to hopefully avoid the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Sorry to answer my own question.

Here is what I did:

- Click *Clear All Associations* on the accounts tab of my EL&U profile page. (not sure if that was actually necessary though). At that point I thought I'd just made things worse.
- Then from the accounts tab on my profile page for each Stack (Math, EL&U, ect), I clicked *Copy [Stack] Profile To Related Accounts*

That fixed the problem. I don't know why and I'm still confused by it all, but now I can see all my accounts. Woot!